# iOS - How can I Convert an Image to unsigned char to print image using Blue Bamboo Printer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, printers, unsigned-char

I am developing one Printer App with Blue Bamboo printer. I want to Print one Image through it but I am unable to convert it to **unsigned char array** as they provide in sample code. How can I do this? Here is a sample code which they provide.

```
 unsigned char buffer3[796]={
     0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31 ,  
     0x19, 0x20, 
     0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03
     ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xB0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xD8 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x13 ,0xEC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x04 
     ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x29 ,0xF4 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x64 ,0xF9 ,0x00
     ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xF9 ,0xC0 ,0x3D ,0xFF
     ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF2 ,0x73 ,0x80 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0
     ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0x7F ,0xFD ,0xE0 ,0x3D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x79 ,0x26 ,0xC0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
     ,0xFF ,0xFD ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x3C ,0x8F ,0x60
     ,0x0C ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0x80
     ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x9E ,0x8F ,0xB0 ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
     ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF8 ,0xFD ,0x80 ,0x33 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
     ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0x4F ,0x27 ,0xD8 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC 
     ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF9 ,0xFD ,0xFF ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x26 ,0x53 ,0xC8
     ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDD ,0xDD ,0xFF
     ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0xC9 ,0xF0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
     ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDF ,0x9D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
     ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC9 ,0xE4 ,0xE0 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x06 
     ,0xE7 ,0xFD ,0xCF ,0x9D ,0x80 ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xF0 ,0xF2 ,0x40
     ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xCF ,0x1D ,0x80
     ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0x79 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDF ,0xFC ,0xFF
     ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC7 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x49 ,0x3D ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9F ,0xFC ,0xFF ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
     ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC2 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1C ,0x9E ,0x00 
     ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x1F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xE1 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC0 ,0x1D ,0xFF
     ,0xE0 ,0xFF ,0xC1 ,0xFF ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x4C ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
     ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00  
     };
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6476959/90172). And it really depends on what data format your printer is expecting.

Comment: It takes only in the mentioned formate. Thats why I want to convert my image to unsigned char array.

Comment: Just googled `0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31`, seems there's an [exact duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036868/how-to-print-image-with-bluebamboo-device-using-objective-c), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093143/how-do-i-convert-a-hex-array-into-a-uiimage) is probably what you need.

Comment: yes you are right Rox but unfortunately it is for MAC OS **NSBitmapImageRep** and **TIFFRepresentation** is not working in iOS.